# Android listview and saving contents

Tags: android

I have a ListActivity with the following adapter

```
this.setListAdapter(new JobTaskItemAdapter(this, jobTaskItems));
```

jobTaskItems is a List and can vary in size from 10 to 100 objects.
The adapter returns a new compound view for each JobTaskItem:-

```
[TextView][EditText][TextView]
```

The user will go through the list and edit the applicable EditText boxes and then select a Save option. I then need to iterate through every view in the list, retrieve the edited text and save it in a JobTaskItem string field which will then be saved to SQLite db.
However I cannot see how to access the data from views that have been scrolled off the screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When ListView item disappears from the screen is can be destroyed/reused. You cannot rely on it then. You should save those data before list is scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

It really has nothing to do with views that have been scrolled off the screen... I think there are a couple issues here, firstly, you should use a scrollView in your xml layout so you can access said fields, and second, Im assuming you are dynamically adding these compund [TextView][EditText][TextView]'s to your layout based on the size of jobTaskItems. What I would be in this case, is in your loop that dynamically adds these views, set references to your Textviews / EditTexts via an array:

```
TextView []TextViewArray1 = new TextView[jobTaskItems.length];
TextView []TextViewArray2 = new TextView[jobTaskItems.length];
EditText []EditTextArray = new EditText[jobTaskItems.length];

int i = 0; //used as array indexer
for (your_dynamically_added_views) {
  YOUR_CODE;
  TextViewArray1[i] = Dynamic_TextView_1;
  TextViewArray2[i] = Dynamic_TextView_2;
  EditTextArray[i] = Dynamic_EditText;
}
```

Then you can access these values later for manipulation